# Confusion with my PHP install

Tags: php, linux, apache

I've made an install of PHP (as apache's module) for ubuntu (version 13.04). 
I follow this instructions of documentation
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

At the end of installation, my php.ini is located and read at /usr/local/lib

Now I need to install GD library. I do this :

```
apt-get install php5-gd
```

and of course restart apache. Extension is not loaded.

I discover i have another php folder under /etc/php5 and installation of gd extension has been made in this directory. By the way, I don't understand why I have another php.ini under /etc/php5/embed.

Do i need to recompile PHP with appropriate option for gd ?

Thanks

---

Command info

```
which php
```

/usr/local/bin/php

```
php --ini
```

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/gd.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/gd.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: Checked if it's enabled via php.ini?

Comment: Try running `which php` and `php --ini` and add the output to the question.

Comment: Also check httpd.conf to see which php module Apache is using.

Comment: @DarylGill You mean extension ? I've added extension=gd.so but no result

Comment: httpd.conf load => LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so

Comment: @kero_zen Are you sure? Because the last ouput states it cannot be opened, or  doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed compile install and deb install 
they are not compatible

you install php via (easiest way)

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

or comile gd form source

Comment: I've uninstall compiled files and run apt-get command to install Apache 2 + PHP 5